# How App Store calculate every app's unique download count?

Tags: algorithm, performance, hadoop, data-structures, analytics

The "unique" means that if an app is downloaded by a user more than 1 time, its download count  remains 1 **forever** until another user download the app again. For example, we track users downloads' behavior as following:

```
Date        User        App name
2012-01-01  jack        Angry Birds
2012-01-01  jack        Angry Birds
2012-01-02  jack        Angry Birds
2012-01-02  paul        Angry Birds
2012-01-02  jack        Snappea
```

This should give results:

```
Angry Birds        2
Snappea            1
```

A simple way to implement it is that we use data structure, such as HashSet to store **User + App name** as its key. But in fact, App Store has plenty of users and apps. Assume the user numer is 400M and it has 650K apps, the HashSet's size will hit 400M * 650K = **260T** in worst situation. We also assume that we need to calculate the download count **every day**.

According [Google Play hits 600,000 apps, 20 billion total installs](http://www.engadget.com/2012/06/27/google-play-hits-600000-apps/), App Store's total downloads number is **30 billion** by June 2012. Still it's a big number.

So how can we implement with less space but also fast? If use hadoop / hbase?

Comment: SQL has DISTINCT and COUNT functionality. Something like: (sorry for rusty SQL, probably will not work but the idea is similar: `SELECT app, COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT app, user FROM myTable t2) FROM myTable t1;`

Comment: That means the database need to store 30 billion rows? I guess it will impact performance when add new records.

Comment: You asked for calculating it every day. Just update the table created by the COUNT every day. An alternative will be to maintain the data in a `Map<App,Set<User>>`, and get the number of unique users by simply `map.get(app).size()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a database: Have a table of `users`. Each user should have a history of downloads. when the user downloads an app it will be added to the history of downloads. If this is a new app it will also update the `app` table (using a trigger) to increase the count. Sounds good?

Comment: Looks good. Thank you for your answer. But how would you do with re-downloaded apps of a user?  @zenpoy

Comment: You increase the count for app only if it's a new app in the users app history.